# How to update Apache Ant version from 1.9.3 to 1.9.4

Tags: java, apache-ant

My O.S. version is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My Apache ant version is 1.9.3.

```
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
```

I want to update my Apache ant 1.9.4.(onwards)

Please help me, because when I'm using `sudo apt-get install ant` to update my ant.

But after this sudo command ant it showing following messages.

> ant is already the newest version.
>
> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
>   required:
>
> aspectj eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp fastjar jarwrapper junit4 
>   libasm3-java libaspectj-java libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
>   libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java
>   libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-compress-java
>   libcommons-dbcp-java   libcommons-digester-java
>   libcommons-httpclient-java libcommons-lang-java   libcommons-pool-java
>   libdb-java libdb-je-java libdb5.3-java   libdb5.3-java-jni
>   libeasymock-java libecj-java libequinox-osgi-java
>   libfelix-bundlerepository-java libfelix-gogo-command-java
>   libfelix-gogo-runtime-java libfelix-gogo-shell-java
>   libfelix-osgi-obr-java   libfelix-shell-java libfelix-utils-java
>   libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java   libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java
>   libgeronimo-osgi-support-java libglade2-0   libgnomecanvas2-0
>   libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common
>   libhamcrest-java libicu4j-4.4-java libicu4j-java libjetty8-java
>   libjline-java libjtidy-java libkxml2-java liblucene2-java
>   libosgi-compendium-java libosgi-core-java libosgi-foundation-ee-java
>   libservlet2.5-java libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni
>   libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java libswt-gtk-3-jni
>   libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libtomcat7-java libxz-java
>   linux-headers-3.13.0-32   linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic
>   linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic   linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
>   linux-signed-image-3.13.0-32-generic   sat4j Use 'apt-get autoremove'
>   to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not
>   upgraded.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to upgrade ?

Answer (score 3):

Open up a Terminal with **(Ctrl + t)**

Remove the installed Ant either by remove or purge:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge ant
```

The output should be something like

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ant* ant-optional*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,057 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 310491 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ant-optional (1.9.3-2build1) ...
Removing ant (1.9.3-2build1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing ant, directory '/usr/share/ant/lib' not empty so not removed
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
```

(I have a jar file in '/usr/share/ant/lib' which I need so I didn't clean that up.)

Download, verify signature, unpack and put the Apache Ant to for example /opt/
(According to their website it is suggested to use the latest version, but we specifically need 1.9.4, right? :-))

```
~$ cd Downloads
~/Downloads$ wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz
~/Downloads$ wget https://www.apache.org/dist/ant/KEYS
~/Downloads$ wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz.asc

~/Downloads$ gpg --import KEYS
~/Downloads$ gpg --verify apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz.asc apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz
~/Downloads$ gpg --fingerprint 82A7FBCD

~/Downloads$ tar -xvzf apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz
~/Downloads$ sudo mv apache-ant-1.9.4 /opt/
```

More information about Apache Signature Verifying:

https://www.apache.org/info/verification.html

Create a symlink to your bin folder so your programs can call it

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant
```

Usually your programs will need the **ANT_HOME** and **ANT_OPTS** environment variables:

```
### ANT-SETUP
export ANT_HOME="/opt/apache-ant-1.9.4"
export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"
```

To make it permanent put the above lines to ~/.bashrc. Here are the commands to do this:
Either use an editor to edit .bashrc or from command line, just use the below commands.

**Create a backup of .bashrc, before doing anything with it.**

```
$ cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc-backup

$ echo "" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "### ANT-SETUP by $USER" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "export ANT_HOME=\"/opt/apache-ant-1.9.4\"" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "export ANT_OPTS=\"-Xmx1024m\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Verify that the changes are correct

```
$ diff ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc-backup
```

The output should be something like:

```
129,130c129
< 
< ### ANT-SETUP by ${your_username}
< export ANT_HOME="/opt/apache-ant-1.9.4"
< export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"
---
>
```

Restart the Terminal or source the .bashrc

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Verify the installation:

```
$ ant -diagnostics
```

Comment: Perfect answer for those still on Trusty, but a slight update to current times: `XX:MaxPermSize` is not supported from Java 8 onwards, so leave it out. Also the archives should be verified before being used, i.e. get the keys: `wget https://www.apache.org/dist/ant/KEYS`, also get the signature `wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz.asc`, import with `gpg --import KEYS` and verify with `gpg --verify apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz.asc`. Update the version numbers to whatever you like. 1.9.9 for example.

Comment: Thank you @kap for taking the time to respond, I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Ant 1.9.3 is the latest stable and supported version for Ubuntu 14.04.
Ant 1.9.4 is the package aimed at Ubuntu 15.04 and is currently only present in the Vivid Vervet repository.

Refer [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ant) for more information.

---

Moreover if you want to upgrade your Ant package in the future you will need to run :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Because `sudo apt-get install <package>` is only for installing a package, not for update it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no particular reason to upgrade to a newer version I would not upgrade.

Besides upgrading to 15.04 (that one has 1.9.4) ...

You could download all the DEB files from the packages page for [Ant](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ant) but I see a snag there: it requires you to also upgrade JRE and that is a lot of work.

Or you need to find 1.9.4 from outside of Ubuntu if you want a version your current release (ie. 14.04) does not provide yet. There is a warning on their website where you can find [1.9.6](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi): "Older releases of Ant can be found here. We highly recommend to not use those releases but upgrade to Ant's latest release. [Older versions can be found here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/)".

The "tar.gz" at the link holds a "install" document that points to the [online manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) and it has a very large part on how to install it and how to make custom configuration settings work.

If you do need to upgrade do pick 1.9.6 over 1.9.4.

Comment: @JalT good on you :) please do not forget to upvote and if applicable accept an answer that suits you best (not does not have to be mine ;-) ) Otherwise the system will keep bumping this question to the frontpage